# What is the capacity of device internal notifications in android?

Tags: android

Can any one tell that  the capacity(count) of device internal notifications in android device??

Comment: Can you just elaborate? what do you mean by internal notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the notifications that pop up into the statusbar, I have been above 50 at some point with my Galaxy S, so its definitely above that. When would you ever want to use more than that?

It is not mentioned in the [notifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/index.html) documentation page, but one would only assume that an upper limit does exist, if not limited by software, it is definitely limited by either ram or space on your device.